# Nested iframe not going fullscreen

Tags: html, iframe, cors

I have 3 html pages.

grandparent.html - Contains 1 iframe with allowfullscreen attribute set with source set to parent.html

parent.html - Contains 1 iframe with allowfullscreen attribute set with source set to child.html

child.html - Contains 1 div with a button which requests fullscreen on the parent

All 3 pages are in the same domain.

Onclick of the button in child.html, I want to make the iFrame in the parent.html go fullscreen when I load up "grandparent.html" in the browser. But this fails. Nothing happens. However, when I load up "parent.html" in the browser, it goes fullscreen.

For some reason the iframe in grandparent.html blocks the iframe in parent.html to go fullscreen. This is strange because the grandparent iframe has allowfullscreen set to true as well.

Also, from the child button onClick handler I can make the iframe of the grandparent go fullscreen by accessing it using parent.parent.document.getElementById('grandParentIframe');

But that is not what I want to do since my grandParent will most probably be on a different Domain. I'm hoping that I can overcome the cross domain restriction by nesting the iFrames but it doesn't work even though right now all three pages have the same domain, host and protocol.

Please help!
SM

Comment: Add some html code please.

Comment: Just a general question but why would you need an i-frame within an i-frame... An i-frame completely loads a page separately and then imports the results into the parent page. I do not know your context code but in general I think you can make anything work with just 1 iframe; please elaborate.

Comment: paste some code and put a demo to get your context.

Comment: here's some code : http://pastebin.com/ndzm6MKL

Devon, my website loads up in another shell (containing the iframe) which I don't have control over. My webpage and the shell are in different domains. So when I try the parents iFrame I get an error saying Domain, Protocol & Port must match. I'm hoping I can get them to add the "allowfullscreen" param in their iframe so that when I take my iFrame (in parent.html) fullscreen, it takes the one in their shell (grandparent.html) fullscreen too. I'm assuming this solution will work cross domain but right now it doesn't work on the same domain either

Comment: did you ever get this sorted out? I have a similar question

Answer (score 0):

this one is pretty simple if you have nested iframes, all you have to do is set each iframe, up the chain, to allowfullscreen.

If you are not able to set the iframe directly from your code, then you need to have the parent page load a script that would allow this, or create an iframe inside of the unfriendly one, that has the same origin of the parent, and load some dedicated scripts from there. I'm not going to go into setting up an iframe buster here, but feel free to ask if you're curious.